# Add a Network Coverage UIView to MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I have an MKMapView - which is working well. I now have some notifications that the ViewController responds to when the network coverage goes down. When this happens, I want to  show a simple UIView with a UILabel that tells the user that the network is down.

I am having lots of lots of problems trying to achieve this. I have built the view in in the Interface Builder and I am initialising it like so in viewDidLoad:

```
 self.networkWarningView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NetworkWarningView"
                                                             owner:nil
                                                           options:nil] lastObject];

 self.networkWarningView.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width / 2) - 140, (self.view.bounds.size.height / 2) - 45, 280, 70);
```

Then I am handling a network down notification using this method:

```
-(void)handleNetworkWarning
    {

        self.hasNetworkFailure = YES;

        BOOL shouldBeAdded = YES;
        for(UIView *view in [self.view subviews]){
            if([view isEqual:self.networkWarningView]){
                shouldBeAdded = NO;
            }
        }

        if(shouldBeAdded){

            self.networkWarningView.alpha = 0.0;

            [self.view addSubview:self.networkWarningView];

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
               self.networkWarningView.alpha = 1.0;
            }];
        }

    }
```

I have tried adding the warningView to the view controller view AND the map view - but neither of these approaches work. I would like to 'animate in' the warning when it occurs.

Any advise to how to best overlay a view on an MkMapView would be appreciated. I thought it would be simple....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was stupid.

Anyone working with Mapkit - remember that any notifications that should result in a UI change should be dispatched to the main thread. I was dispatching them to a background worker thread so no wonder nothing was happening!